# How to use \1 sed command in csh script

Tags: csh

I am working on old CSH script and updating the script. i am woking on sed command and using \1 but somehow the script is not working. When i use the same command in terminal, it is properly working. Could you please help me with that

```
set varun=(lat[0]in fooin booin again ertyin)
foreach iso (`echo $varun:q`)
      set a=`echo "$iso" | sed -r 's/\(.*\)in/\1/g'`
      echo $a
 end
```

Comment: I tried running `echo latin | sed -r 's/\(.*\)in/\1/g'` in csh and it worked.

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Comment: it is showing set: No match

Comment: @jjramsey sorry, i have updated the question

Comment: I get the "set: No match" error message just by running `set varun=(lat[0]in fooin booin again ertyin)` from a csh prompt. Your problem does not appear to have anything to do with sed.

Comment: What could be fix for this issue

Comment: Given that I have no idea why you added `[0]` to `latin`, I don't know. I would strongly recommend that you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask